# Import many folders in Eclipse to one project each

Tags: java, eclipse, import, directory, collision

I have about 200 folders with four *.java* files per folder. The files inside these folders are all named the same. There are no *.classpath* or *.project* files.

I want to import all of these folders/projects into Eclipse (to automatically analyze them).

Simply using the 'import' function does not work, because all of the files have the same name. Putting all of them in different packages in the src folder doesn't work either - I would have to assign a package name in each class.

Are there any obvious ways of importing all these files I didn't think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those java file don´t have a ´package´ instruction you could create Java Project to do this task.

Copy all the folders into this new project folder.

Generate with cat/grep/sed or a tool like that, a portion of xml to put in the .classpath file, which will make those folders Source folders.

They will be able to hold some java classes without package (because they will all be in the default package, for each source folder).

The xml to be generated for each folder:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="folder1"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="folder2"/>
...
<classpathentry kind="src" path="folderN"/>
```

Comment: I made all of them a source folder by right-clicking and selecting "Build Path --> Use as source folder". This worked as well. Thus I cannot really work with those classes in Eclipse (due to the "same name problem" - but nevertheless my analysis plugin can create reports!

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the classes with the same names? You could create some sort of script or a small Java program to rename them (file name + class name). Or go for the other solution and make the program add the package declaration for you.

Comment: Thought of that as well, but I hoped there would be an easier solution... Anyways - you solution solved my problem. Thanks!